# Django - Create forms with loops

Tags: python, django

I have a model called comments and I am displaying them using a for loop in the template.
I want the users to be able to edit these forms without having to go into a different page (kind of like Youtube Comments) but I'm not sure how I will go about creating these forms in a loop and more importantly how to handle the post requests.

Thanks in advance.

Models.py

```
    class Comments(models.Model):
        text = models.CharField(max_length=500, default='')
        poster = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
        post = models.ForeignKey(Posts, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.poster) + " " + str(self.post)
```

Views.py (the important bits)

```
comments = Comments.objects.filter(post=pst).order_by('-id')
args = {'user': request.user, 'pst': pst, 'serv': serv, 'managers': serv.managers.all(), 'form': form, 'comform': comform, 'score': score, 'comments':comments}
return render(request, 'viewpost.html', args)
```

Comment: Add sample code

Comment: i mean its literally just {% for com in comments %} <p>{{ com.text }}</p> {% endfor %}

Comment: Can you add your models.py, forms.py and views.py? Should clarify a lot more.

Comment: Ok. I've added them. I cut out all the unrelated code in my views but is that fine?

Comment: This might help you. it allows you to send a request by ajax  https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/29/how-to-work-with-ajax-request-with-django.html

Comment: i figured it out but thanks, this will probably help me with some other things I wanted to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure it out own my own.

For anyone that is wondering, I set the value of the submit button to the id of each comment. Then when a post request was made, I just go the comment object with that id and saved the EditCommentForm with that comment as the instance.